# Is opening a shared memory multiple times bad in any way?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, shared-memory

I have a class which opens a posix shared memory using [shm_open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open). Now I have to create objects of this class multiple times (5-10 objects total), and that means the same shared memory is going to be opened that many times.

The shared memory has variable size, and can be from 1k to 500k.

The questions regarding this are :
1. Is this going to cause increased memory usage? (I do not see this happening, so my guess is no)
2. Is this going to cause bad performances when accessing shared memory?
3. Anything else that can go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on the page you linked shm_open to:

> shm_open() **creates and opens a *new*, or opens an *existing***, POSIX shared memory object. A POSIX shared memory object is in effect a handle which can be used by unrelated processes to mmap(2) the same region of shared memory.

To access a shared memory object, you need a handle to it. shm_open() can be used both to open (create) new, and reopen existing shared memory object. No memory increase nor bad performances occur when reopening an existing object.

Answer (score 3):

It will not increase memory usage, however you use up handles each time you open a shared memory and you may run out. (Each process has a limit to the number of open handles.)

You need to manage access to the shared memory possibly using synchronization objects such as semaphores.

Mmap maps to a different base-address each time, so storing pointers pointing into shared memory is a bad idea.

Comment: I am very far from reaching the number of handles limit. Regarding other two concerns - well, it is very easy to tackle them in c++ by initializing in the constructor, and deinitializing properly in the destructor.

Comment: If you access the shared memory from different processes, I don't see how you can address synchronization issues at the constructor and destructor. You need to control access with a mutex each time you read and write to the shared memory. With regards to the final concern, how I also don't understand how it can be mitigated by constructor / destructor. Some form of relative addressing is needed.

Comment: ops I meant that for the last issue (regarding the mmap-ing that area). For the synchronization issue, I am using message queues to inform a process when a shared memory was written - only then that process is reading that memory area.